# Hide Xcode 4.3 Toolbar not available in Full screen mode

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3

I just wonder if there is a possibility to hide the toolbar of Xcode in FullScreen mode. It seems that this is not possible: in the context menu hide is grayed out, the key commend won't work either.

On a small screen like a MBA, it would be great to have both, full screen and hidden toolbar.

Is there a hidden way? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: just to make my point clearer

a)This is the height of the toolbar in the normal screen mode

[image]

b)This is the height in hidden toolbar mode in the normal screen mode

[image]

c)This is the hight in full screen mode

[image]

I would like to have the hidden toolbar b) to be available in fullscreen mode c). This is currently not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not supported in Xcode, but Ole Zorn made a [plugin](https://github.com/omz/MiniXcode) which adds some very useful scheme selection stuff to Xcode. I extended it with a menu option for hiding the full-screen toolbar: https://github.com/tkemp/MiniXcode. It adds a new View menu item "Show/Hide Toolbar in Full Screen."

This is currently a pull request on the original ( https://github.com/omz/MiniXcode ), but if you grab mine from the first link above and build it you should get what you want. Change the base SDK in the project to 10.7 if you're on Lion, otherwise it's ready to go.

Base SDK: [image]

Comment: sounds cool, thanks. But: it doesn't seem to work here with Xcode 4.5.2  I used the link https://github.com/tkemp/MiniXcode   downloaded, built and restarted Xcode, but the fullscreen toolbar is still there as before. The plug-in is at the right place. Any idea?

Comment: What version of Mac OS are you on? Check the "Base SDK" to make sure it matches. Do you see new items in the View menu?

Comment: its 10.8 here and that is what is in the deployment target

Comment: OK do you see the two new items in the View menu? ("Scheme Selection in Title Bar" and "Show Toolbar in Full Screen")

Comment: Ahhh, okay, thanks :-)  That works! Many thanks for posting.This really saves a lots of space, especially on the 11.6 inch